# Excel: Find and Replace Macro - One Column Only

Tags: vba, excel

I've written some macros to format a load of data into the same accepted format, the program we pull from refuses to pull the data how we want it but in theory it wouldn't be hard to change in Excel.

The way it is set to run is to have separate macros for the modifiers and then a 'Run All' macro that just does a Call to them all.

Currently I have:

```
Sub ReplaceTitleMs()
'
' Strips Mrs from Headteacher Name
'
'
'
 Columns("V").Select
 Cells.Replace What:="Ms ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

But when I run this, it strips Ms from the whole sheet and one column requires Ms to still be in the Cells (this is column W)

An example of the data is effectively:

```
Ms Helen Smith
Ms Brenda Roberts
Ms Kirsty Jones
```

But there are many other titles being used so I would like to just run a Find and Replace on the column that has to be selected by the macro.

The macro works find on the column I want it to...I just need to restrict it to that column!

Comment: The problem is that using `Cells` without qualifying it with a range means all the cells on the worksheet. The `Select` on column V is irrelevant.

Comment: I'd identified that bit as probably being the problematic part, just wasn't quite sure what to do about it! Thanks guys

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to properly qualify the range for the `Replace()` method

```
Sub ReplaceTitleMs()
    Columns("V").Replace    What:="Ms ", _
                            Replacement:="", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect, I knew I wasn't far away but re-recording wasn't producing it like that. Many thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Based on your data (which is properly capitilised), to avoid false matches you should set `MatchCase` to True to avoid culling the likes of
`Mrs Nancy Adams` to `Mrs Nancy Ada`

```
Columns("V").Replace "Ms ", vbNullString, xlPart, xlByRows, True
```

To be completely bullet-proof, you would either

1. Use `AutoFilter`for the detection and removal
2. Build a range of matches with `Find` and `FindNext`, then remove only the first three characters where the match is correct

Answer (score 0):

### Search and Replace in selected-cells

1. press the "`ALT + F11`" keys shortcut (i.e. hold `ALT` key down and press `F11` key at last release both) to open the **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications** window.
2. Click "`Insert > Module`" (i.e. from "`Insert`" menu click "`Module`"), and paste the following code in the Module Window.

```vb
Sub ReplaceInSelection()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim workRng As Range
    Dim find$
    Dim replace$
On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set workRng = Application.Selection
    Set workRng = Application.InputBox("Range", "Select Range", workRng.Address, Type:=8)
    find = Application.InputBox("Find:", "Select what to find")
    replace = Application.InputBox("Replace with:", "Select replacement")
    For Each rng In workRng
        If rng.Value = find Then
            rng.Value = replace
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

3. for now close **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications** window
4. and Select the range of url text that you want to convert to clickable hyperlinks.
5. Then press "`ALT + F8`" key (or just `F5` in older excel), to run the code click run while "`ReplaceInSelection`" is selected
6. then a pop-up dialog will open for you to change previously selected range, then click `OK`
7. then another pop-up dialog will open for to specify what you want to `find`
8. then, at last, a pop-up dialog will open for you to specify with what you want to `replace` any occurrence of what was found

all done! the selected cells have been searched for what you specified to `find` and was changed with again what you specified to `replace with`.