# VBA for find/replace using list of parameters from file and include spaces in search string

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find

The goal is to provide a list of replacement strings in a file so that it can be reused with VBA.
Currently I do this manually and need to include leading and/or trailing space on the search term to differentiate the possible results.

For example: "Module E whatever" is searched for " E " and replaced with "East". The result is "Module East whatever". 
But I don't know how to provide spaces within the search string to a subroutine that processes many search/replace pairs.

target spreadsheet:
[image]

replacement input parameters file:

```
slv,Slave
ign,Igniter 
" e ",East 
west,West
vlv,Valve
err, Error
ERROR, Error
spk, Spark
detectd, Detected
"DET", Detected
Module, Module
```

And the code so far:

```
Sub OpenReplacementParametersFile()
    Dim file As String
    file = "replacement pairs.csv"
    Open file For Input As #1
    Worksheets("TestSheet").Select
    Dim parm1 As String
    Dim parm2 As String
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, LineFromFile
        lineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
        parm1 = lineItems(0)
        parm2 = lineItems(1)

        'Call FindReplaceTextForColumnC(lineItems(0), lineItems(1))
        Call FindReplaceTextForColumnC(parm1, parm2)
    Loop

End Sub

' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530193/excel-find-and-replace-macro-one-column-only
Sub FindReplaceTextForColumnC(findStr As String, newStr As String)
    Columns("C").Replace What:=findStr, _
                            Replacement:=newStr, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

Appreciate any feedback/comments (even snarky ones).
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me what the question is. If you're only seeking feedback then CodeReview is a more appropriate forum.

Comment: he want to replace each word in Origin Column from list replacement.. result is target column then last column

Comment: I'd suggest looking into Regular Expressions where you can use a word boundary token instead of a space to define the strings.  Although you'd have to do something different for `"DET"'